# Attach eventhandler for Webview in electron

Tags: node.js, electron

I loaded an external Url in a webview in electron.

I need to attach an eventhandler to a click on elements that are marked by a certain class. The handler should execute in the context of the hosting page similiar to the eventhandler loadstart  in the sample.
Is this possible?

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Some eventhandler test</h1>
    <div class="indicator" >

  </div>
 <div id="content" ></div>
  <webview id="cmsWebview" src="http:///www.stackoverflow.com" style="height:100vh;display: flex;"></webview>
   <script>
 onload = function() {
    var webview = document.getElementById("cmsWebview");
    var indicator = document.querySelector(".indicator");

    var loadstart = function() {
      indicator.innerText = "loading...";
    }
    var loadstop = function() {
      indicator.innerText = "...finished loading";
    }
    webview.addEventListener("did-start-loading", loadstart);
    webview.addEventListener("did-stop-loading", loadstop);
  }
 </script>
  </body>
</html>
```